# Is there a way to show users that the content has been automatically translated?

Tags: rules, i18n-l10n

I am using the [Translation Management Tool](http://drupal.org/project/tmgmt) module to translate my nodes automatically. What I want is for users to see whether the node they are seeing (in their language) is the translated, or the original one. I managed to make the translation (when node is saved, it is translated) and with rules I can change value of e.g. some integer field, but it changes on both nodes: original and the translated one.

How can I change it only in translated one?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting an integer field, create a text field called original language or source language. Use Rules to store the language code of the source language when the node is created. That way the value of the field is correct regardless of which language the user is viewing the node.

You can then compare the source language of the node with the user's current language and display a message if they do not match.